# More than one socket stops all sockets from working

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

I have a few computers on a network and I'm trying to coordinate work between them by broadcasting instructions and receiving replies from individual workers.  When I use zmq to assign a single socket to each program it works fine, but when I try to assign another, none of them work.  For example, the master program runs on one machine.  With the code as such it works fine as a publisher, but when I uncomment the commented lines neither socket works.  I've seen example code extremely similar to this so I believe it should work, but I must be missing something.

Here's some example code, first with the master program and then the worker program.  The idea is to control the worker programs from the master based on input from the workers to the master.

```
import zmq
import time
import sys

def master():
    word = sys.argv[1]
    numWord = sys.argv[2]
    port1 = int(sys.argv[3])
    port2 = int(sys.argv[4])
    context = zmq.Context() 
    publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port1)

    #receiver = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    #receiver.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port2)

    for i in range(int(numWord)):
        print str(i)+": "+word
        print "Publishing 1"
        publisher.send("READY_FOR_NEXT_WORD")
        print "Publishing 2"
        publisher.send(word)
        #print "Published.  Waiting for REQ"
        #word = receiver.recv()
        #receiver.send("Master IRO")
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Received: "+word
    publisher.send("EXIT_NOW")


master()
```

Ditto for the workers:

```
import zmq
import random
import zipfile
import sys

def worker(workerID, fileFirst, fileLast):
    print "Worker "+ str(workerID) + " started"
    port1 = int(sys.argv[4])
    port2 = int(sys.argv[5])

    # Socket to talk to server
    context = zmq.Context()

    #pusher = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    #pusher.connect("tcp://10.122.102.45:%s" % port2)

    receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    receiver.connect ("tcp://10.122.102.45:%s" % port1)
    receiver.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')




    found = False
    done = False
    while True:
        print "Ready to receive"
        word = receiver.recv()
        print "Received order: "+word
        #pusher.send("Worker #"+str(workerID)+" IRO "+ word)
        #pusher.recv()
        #print "Confirmed receipt"



worker(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `PUB-SUB` patterns are not meant to be reliable specially on initialization (while the connection is established).

Your "master" publishes the first two messages in that loop and then waits for a request from the "worker". Now, if those messages get lost (something that may happen with the first messages sent with `PUB-SUB` patterns), then the "worker" will be stuck waiting for a publication from the "master". So, basically, they are both stuck waiting for an incoming message.

Apart from that, notice that you are publishing 2 messages from the "master" node while only processing 1 from the "worker". Your "worker" wont be able to catch-up with your "master" and, therefore, messages will be dropped or you'll get a crash.